# Vertically centered element not scrolling on overflow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML & CSS, which lets me vertically center an element.

I also have a blurred background element, which is put in the background using `z-index`

If I resize my window to a point where the centered element causes an overflow (x or y), scrolling the window vertically or horizontally will keep the element fixed on its position.

Removing `position:fixed` from `.page-content` will cause the `background-blur` div to come up in front of the element.

What can I do in order to make the window scrollable when the window is too small to display the entire element?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha29h4p6/2/)

HTML (wrapped in body):

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="background-blur"></div>
        <div class="page-content">
          <div class="vertical-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                  <div class="centered-placeholder" style="width:500px; height:750px; background-color:black;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .container {
    height:100%;
    min-height:750px;
    overflow:auto;
  }

  .background-blur {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:500px;
    background:url("somefile.jpg");
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
    -moz-filter: blur(50px);
    -o-filter: blur(50px);
    -ms-filter: blur(50px);
    filter: blur(50px);
  }

  .page-content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  }

  .vertical-center{
    height:750px;
    margin-top:100px;
  }

  @media (min-height: 750px) {
    .vertical-center {
      margin-top: 0px;
      min-height: 750px;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `position: absolute|relative;` on `.page-content`? You need a non-static `position` in order for `z-index` to apply. You've chosen `fixed`, but the disadvantage of that is that `fixed` elements, by definition, don't scroll.

Try switching to `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` to maintain the `z-index`, while gaining scrolling functionality!

Comment: Thank you! I knew it'd be something simple like this! I only tried `auto` and removing it. I also did `absolute` on the `background-blur`, but not on the element. Setting it to `position: absolute` works perfectly.

Comment: good to hear :) when css works, it works! (And when it doesn't... it fails horribly!!)